# Integral in terms of a parametric variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, leibniz-integral-rule

I have a challenging integral in front of me, which has evaded all types of substitutions and seems to be intractible to me(P.S.:I am a high schooler). Here it is:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^a-1}{\ln (x)}$$

My teacher says that it can be solved by the method of differentiation. Is he referring to differentiation under the integral sign (which I have only heard about)? How do I go about this question?

I have tried the substitutions $x^a=t$ and then $\ln (t)=u$ which has led to a more compact form.

Comment: Yes, he is referring to differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: See the following answer on [Finding the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^a - 1}{\log x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1231750/323432). On the first step, they use the fact that if $b$ and $c$ are constants, then:
$$\frac{d}{da}\left(\int_b^c f(a,x)~dx\right)=\int_b^c \frac{\partial}{\partial a} f(a,x)~dx$$
This is a special case of [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most commonly used examples of differentiation under the integral sign or Feynman's Trick. Here, differentiate with respect to $a$ and that immediately gives you an easy-to-integrate expression.

The motive behind that is because when we differentiate $f(z)=z^a$ with respect to $a$, what's left is a natural log: $f'(z)=z^a\log z$. The $\log z$ term can then cancel with our denominator, leaving something trivial to deal with. To wit, differentiating gives$$I'(a)=\frac {\partial}{\partial a}\int\limits_0^1dx\,\frac {x^a-1}{\log x}=\int\limits_0^1dx\, x^a=\frac 1{a+1}$$Integrating the expression back to retrieve $I(a)$ leaves$$I(a)=\log(a+1)+C$$Now all we have to do is find the constant $C$. This can be easily found by finding a suitable value of $a$ such that $I(a)$ and $\log(a+1)$ can be easily evaluated. I will leave this up to the OP if he is interested in finishing this problem. Here is the final answer, hidden in all of its glory

> $$\int\limits_0^1dx\,\frac {x^a-1}{\log x}\color{blue}{=\log(a+1)}$$

Here's an extra practice problem (slightly more difficult, but still feasible)$$I=\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\,\frac {\log\left(\frac {1+x^{11}}{1+x^3}\right)}{(1+x^2)\log x}$$Anyone who solves it gets to feel good about themselves!

Comment: Thank you Frank W for your time. I have understood it. Could you tell me some resources on this trick of differentiating under the Integral sign. I will try the practice problem too.

Comment: @Sidharth No problem! For the practice problem, it’ll be a bit difficult if you’re completely new to DUI. But I’m sure you’ll get it eventually with time..