# Is there a solution to $\int \frac{x^7-2}{\ln x}dx$ without the $\text{Ei}(x)$ and $\text{Li}(x)$ integral?

Tags: integration

I found this question in writing so *perhaps* I have made an error in the handwriting interpretation. I think it should involve a simple $u$-substitution but Wolfram Alpha gives an answer involving the $\text{Ei}(x)$ and $\text{Li}(x)$ integral. Is there a substitution if the exponent was to power $2$ instead of $7$?

Answer (score 0):

As a hint you can take $x=e^u$ so
$dx=e^udu$ and $$x^y=(e^u)^7=e^{7u}\\ \ln(x)=u$$ Can you take over ?

Answer (score 0):

The primary definition of $\text{Li}(x)$ is
$$ \text{Li}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{\ln(t)} $$
so there is no way, in this case, to get away from $\text{Li}(x)$. The integral in question is seen to be:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{ x^{a} - b}{\ln(x)} \, dx &= \int \frac{e^{a \, \ln(x)}}{\ln(x)} \, dx - b \, \text{Li}(x) = \text{Ei}((a+1) \, \ln(x)) - b \, \text{Li}(x) + c_{0}.
\end{align}

If the limits of the integral, for example, are $(0,1)$ and $b=1$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a} - 1}{\ln(x)} \, dx &= [\text{Ei}((a+1) \, \ln(x)) - \text{Li}(x) ]_{0}^{1} = \ln(1+a) 
\end{align}
For a different set of methods see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231738/finding-the-integral-int-01-fracxa-1-log-x-dx?rq=1).